# Python base class calling __init__ in subclass

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am trying to make a war card game in python that improves on an example in a book called the Self Taught Programmer.  In my version I want to follow the rules found on the bicycle cards website.  To get back to my problem I wrote two classes Stack and a Deck class inheriting Stack.

Decks **init** populates the empty list variable cards from the base class with all 52 cards in a deck and shuffles them.  I go to test the classes in IDLE and find out when I create objects of Stack it seems like the **init** from Deck gets called and populates the card variable in the parent class when no subclass object gets created.  How is this?  From my understanding parent classes don't see child classes.

```
from random import shuffle

class Card:
        suits = ["Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]
        values = [None, None, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
                "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
        def __init__(self, v, s):
                self.value = self.values[v]
                self.suit = self.suits[s]

        def __repr__(self):
                return self.value + " of " \
                    + self.suit
        def __lt__(self, c2):
                if self.value < c2.value:
                    return True
                if self.value == c2.value:
                    if self.suit < c2.suit:
                        return False
                return False
        def __gt__(self, c2):
                if self.value > c2.value:
                    return True
                if self.value == c2.value:
                        if self.suit > c2.suit:
                                return False
                return False
        def __eq__(self, c2):
                if self.value == c2.value:
                        return True
                else:
                        return False

class Stack:
    cards = []
  
    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)
    
    def addToBottom(self, card):
        self.cards.insert(0, card)

    def removeCard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def __repr__(self):
        idx = len(self.cards) - 1
        return self.cards[idx]

class Deck (Stack):
    
    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(2, 15):
            for j in range(0, 4):
                self.cards.append(Card(i, j))
        shuffle(self.cards)
```

Comment: I ran your code and I can't reproduce your problem. Can you share what you typed into IDLE?

Comment: You need to show how you are using the classes. - Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `cards` as a class attribute. If you create a `Deck` first, *then* a `Stack`, the creation of the deck populates the `Stack.cards` attribute that everyone shares.

You need to make `cards` an instance attribute:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    . . .
```